# How to give fixed width for the columns inside table in HTML?

Tags: css, html, html-table, column-width

**P.S : Please don't mark as duplicate until you have read the entire question**

I have a `table` where in I want to give fixed width to the `columns` as I want to display them dynamically. The width of the `table` is 100%. So in that `table`, only 1 column or 3 or 6, etc can be displayed. But the problem is if in a scenario I have only 1 column the data in that table occupies the entire 100% `table` even though i have given fixed width to the column. I want the column width to be fixed irrespective of the table width. Please guide where I am wrong. Below is the code I have been trying.

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  word-break: break-all;
}
table td {
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%" cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
  <col width="100px" />
  <col width="50px" />
  <col width="50px" />

  <tr>
    <th>First Column</th>
    <th>Second Column</th>
    <th>Third Column</th>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Text 1</td>
    <td>text 2</td>
    <td>text 3</td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You don't need table layout. just use divs with float: left. because you have fixed widths.

Comment: @Mr_Green : But the problem is the data occupies the entire 100% of the table even though i have given fixed width of 100px or 50 px or so on

Comment: It is because you are using table. You don't need table layout here.

Comment: @Shirish: Your are getting issue with table width "100%". you can fix this issue using fixed width (i.e. 400px) instead of using percentage.

Comment: Those widths are calculated relative to each other. So `100`, `50` and `50` means the 2nd and 3rd are half the width of the 1st. For instance `28`, `14` and `14` will give the same result, switching `px` to `%` or `pt` or whatever doesn't matter either (there seem to be some rounding errors when using float values or `table_width:100%`, but that's about it). All columns combined will always fill the entire with of the table, that's just how tables are designed to behave.

Comment: @Shirish : You can use css property like this **:nth-child(n)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Add hidden column to the end of table.**

Table will be 100% width and resize hidden column than you resize the page.

**Code example:**

```css
table
    {
        table-layout: fixed;
        word-break: break-all;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width:100%;
    }
td
    {
        height:50px;
        border: 1px solid;
    }
th
    {
        height:50px;
        border: 1px solid;
    }
.F
    {
        width:100%;
        border:none;
        border-left:1px solid;
    }
```

```html
<table>
      <col width='200px' />
      <col width='100px' />
      <col width='50px' />
      <tr>
            <th>First Column</th>
            <th>Second Column</th>
            <th>Third Column</th>
            <th class='F'></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
            <td>Text 1</td>
            <td>text 2</td>
            <td>text 3</td>
            <td class='F'></td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I have upvoted your answer bro for your effort. But though it wont work if i am making use of cols to define width of the columns. Tried it.

Comment: You can define width by using cols. If you leave hidden column in the end of table, it works (tested).

Comment: I tried your same code using cols  but for me it didnt work. Can you please modify your answer for it. If it works out i will accept your answer.

Comment: If using cols you must remove width parameters from CSS. Done, code updated

Comment: Accepted :).. Thanks buddy :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, td, th {
border: 1px solid black;
 }

 table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
   }

th {
height: 50px;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>

  <h2>The width and height Properties</h2>
  <p>Set the width of the table, and the height of the table header row:</p>

  <table>
<tr>
  <th>First Column</th>
  <th>Second Column</th>
  <th>Third Column</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Text 1</td>
  <td>Text 2</td>
  <td>Text 3</td>
  </tr>

  </table>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Removing one column from the table makes the other td occupy the entire width. Not working bro.

Comment: Please tell me your complete problem what do you want to acheive?

Comment: As per your above code if i am removing any column , the width of the other 2 tds should not get adjusted to the width of the table.

Comment: If you remove column you need to remove its row too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly different approach. In this example, it will take an auto width table and then fix the width and column widths. I've found this useful where I have an auto width table that I want to filter without the table resizing.

This example makes use of the `col` and `th` elements on a well formed table.

The use of the `fixed` class is added so that the table can be reset easily.

```
/*jQuery - mistajolly - fix table widths*/
var table = $(this);
if(!table.hasClass('fixed')){
    table.width(table.outerWidth(true));
    table.addClass('fixed');
    var cols = table.find('col');
    table.find('th').each(function(index){
        $(cols[index]).width($(this).outerWidth(true)).addClass('fixed');
    });
}

/* Reset and remove fixed widths */
if(table.hasClass('fixed')){
    table.removeClass('fixed').css('width','');
    table.find('.fixed').each(function(index){
        $(this).removeClass('fixed').css('width','');
    });
}
```